# How to alias a URL path to another URL path (apache2)?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, networking, domain-name-system, debian

I've tried everything. `Alias`, `ProxyPass`, different config files (`sites-available/000-default.conf`, `mods-enabled/alias.conf`). My issue is simple. I have an `apache2` server hosted at `xyz.com/name/`. I'd like to alias `xyz.com/name` so it is treated as `xyz.com/name/` and routing works properly.

`xyz.com` is the main server (university-owned) and proxies requests to `xyz.com/name/`, which my server is under.

Apache2 web server running on Debian.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for comment

In general:  a server  has a hostname,  such as `example.com` , not a URI that includes both a hostname and directory path such as `example.com/name`.

Now there can be a mapping that maps a particular directory path from the server that hosts `example.com` to *a different (back-end) server*. That is usually called a reverse proxy (although some appliances/tools implement such mappings slightly differently).

It sounds like your server is the back-end server, let's call that `name.internal.example.com`.

It is the responsibility of whomever manages `example.com` to ensure that `http(s)://example.com/name/` *with* a trailing <kbd>/</kbd>  is mapped the same as `http(s)://example.com/name` *without* a trailing <kbd>/</kbd>.

Generally it will help when you deploy your content in the same directory that the front-end uses for your content, i.e. in the directory `/name`

Then  `http(s)://example.com/name`  can be mapped to `http(s)://name.internal.example.com/name`  (note that both omit the trailing forward slash) - That usually ensures that when requests such as `http(s)://example.com/name/` `http(s)://example.com/name/path/to/some/content`  will also be mapped correctly to your back-end server.

Typically that requires no particular complicated configuration in your apache back-end server. A minimal VitrtualHost block like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName name.internal.example.com
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/html" 
</VirtualHost>
```

and publish your web content in the directory `/var/www/html/name`

Comment: Thank you. Could you please add how the person managing `example.com` could ensure trailing `/` is mapped to the same as without trailing `/`? I will accept your answer.

Comment: That completely depends on what technology they use in the reverse proxy. In Apache for example that would typically be `ProxyPass "/name" "http(s)://name.internal.example.com/name"